# How to run a script when a resource group is deleted?

Tags: azure

I would like to run some custom cleanup script in powershell or Az CLI to cleanup some resources that get created in a resource group but do not get cleaned up automatically when the resource group is deleted.

I can run a custom script manually and then delete the resource group, but I was wondering if there was a way to have it setup so a script is called automatically when the resource group is deleted from the Portal from example.

Comment: "*some resources that get created in a resource group but do not get cleaned up automatically when the resource group is deleted.*" This is interesting for me to hear, as my assumption was that any resource that's created within a resource group is terminated when the resource group itself is deleted. Is that not the case? Can you link to some documentation on this? I'd like to read more on this phenomenon and which resources fall into this category.

Comment: Also - what have you tried? This is the exact purpose of Azure Event Grid - all you'd have to do is subscribe to your subscription(s) as an event source, then route the associated data to your script exposed as an Azure Function.

Comment: For example some service principals that get created as part of a deploymentScript, they will stay after the resource group is deleted. I am new to Azure and don't know all they keywords yet. In AWS I can use a Lambda function that gets called when it is deleted (as part of a cloud formation stack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Azure Automation:

> Azure Automation delivers a cloud-based automation and configuration service that supports consistent management across your Azure and non-Azure environments. It comprises process automation, configuration management, update management, shared capabilities, and heterogeneous features. Automation gives you complete control during deployment, operations, and decommissioning of workloads and resources.
>
> [image: Azure Automation]
>
> Source: [An introduction to Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/media/automation-overview/automation-overview.png)

You can use an Event Grid event as the trigger to run your automation runbook.